# Conditionally aggregating data while also grouping by site

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I'm working with a large case-level dataset and am brand new to python. The dataset in general looks something like this:

```
Site          Type          Value
A              Red            10
A              Blue           15
B              Red            35
B              Yellow          5
C              Blue           45
C              Red            25
```

I'm trying to automate some of our processes with python which involves aggregating the data and grouping it by the site. The output I need would look like this:

```
Site         RedType    BlueType   YellowType    Value0-20    Value20-40    Value40+
A               1           1          0              2            0           0
B               1           0          1              1            1           0
C               1           1          0              0            1           1
```

Based on my limited understanding of what I'm doing so far, I believe the solution I stumbled upon is creating a dictionary with a field for each column I need and applying that as part of grouping by the site:

```
def my_agg(data):
    names = {
        'RedType': data[data['Type']=="Red"]['Id'].count(),
        'BlueType': data[data['Type']=="Blue"]['Id'].count(),
        'YellowType':data[data['Type']=="Yellow"]['Id'].count(),
        'Value0-20': data[data['Value']>=0]['Id'].count() and data[data['Value']<=20]['Id'].count()
        etc........
    return pd.Series(names)

df = data.groupby('Site').apply(my_agg)
```

I'm aware now that the and operator isn't going to work for the value field but the rest has worked so far. Is there a way to conditionally count the value (counting each case between two different values) using this method? And either way, am I overlooking some other way that I could be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to compute bins of the value, then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the Type/Value columns, finally count with [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and flatten the MultiIndex:

```
tmp = (df.assign(Value=lambda d: pd.cut(d['Value'],
                                        bins=[0, 20, 40, np.inf],
                                        labels=['0-20', '20-40', '40+']))
         
          .melt('Site')
      )

out = pd.crosstab(tmp['Site'], [tmp['variable'], tmp['value']])

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

out = out.reset_index()
```

Alternatively, using a loop and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
index = 'Site'

# the following command modifies the original input in place
df['Value'] = pd.cut(df['Value'],
                     bins=[0, 20, 40, np.inf],
                     labels=['0-20', '20-40', '40+'])

out = pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df[index], df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}_')
                 for col in df.columns.difference([index])],
                axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  Site  Type_Blue  Type_Red  Type_Yellow  Value_0-20  Value_20-40  Value_40+
0    A          1         1            0           2            0          0
1    B          0         1            1           1            1          0
2    C          1         1            0           0            1          1
```